# selenium webdriver scape works in localhost but not in production - error 500

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, deployment

Im trying to scape table from a public website and i get an error (code 500),

```
const chrome = require('chromedriver');
const webdriver = require ('selenium-webdriver'),
    { By } = webdriver;

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .forBrowser('chrome').build()

driver.get(websiteurl);

function x() {
   try {
     let table =  await driver.findElement(By.xpath(validXpath)).getAttribute("innerText");
     return table;
   } catch (err) {
      throw err;
   }

}
```

its working localy, but after deployment I get err code 500,
what could be the problem?

the xpath I copied from chrome: Copy => "Copy Xpath"

the website url is like this "https://www.someotherwebsite/path"

must say, i dont need this website to open in another windows, only to get the table and return it to me.

Comment: Is there a chance that a proxy blocks you?

Comment: maybe, I dont know what proxy is. should I put proxy in package.json?

Comment: First of all, you have to check if you have a proxy. If you will navigate to this URL manually you get 500?

Comment: no, this url is public news website, the scape is working in localhost but not after deployment.. only in production mode i get the 500 err